# Get enum instance given the value of it's custom attribute

Tags: c#, enums, attributes

recently I've tried googling and searching for answer how could I get the enum instance where enum values have custom attributes. I get on input a value of its custom attribute and I want to know which enum value corresponds.

Example:

```
public enum whatever
{
    [MyCustomAttribute("foo1", "foo2")]
    SOMETHING,

    [MyCustomAttribute("foo2", "foo3")]
    SOMETHING_2
}
```

...
Attribute:

```
public MyCustomAttribute() : Attribute
{
    string somevalue;
    string anothervalue;

    public MyCustomAttribute(string f, string f2)
    {
        somevalue = f;
        anothervalue = f2;
    }
}
```

I get "foo1" as an input and I want to return whatever.SOMETHING.

Comment: Nice, I couldn't find this one, I guess I didn't enter the right keywords. It's very similar, it should do.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a simple solution which works for me perfectly and I'm very surprised I was not able to find it anywhere.

```
public whatever GetWhatever(string value)
    => typeof(whatever).GetEnumValues()
        .Cast<whatever>().First(val => val .GetCustomAttributeee<MyCustomAttribute>().somevalue == value);
```

I'll be glad if u gimme some feedback about my solution and its problems if any.

Comment: You should check the attribute is not null - in the event that the member doesn't have the attribute on it.

Comment: Oh, well, didn't think of that, thanks!